# MCrypt rijndael-256 to OpenSSL aes-256-ecb conversion

Tags: php, openssl, php-7.2

Since Mcrypt is deprecated, I want to use OpenSSL instead in my code since we already using php 7.2.4 in our server.

I have used following code for Encryption/Decryption.

//ENCRYPTION

```
function encrypt($text, $salt='') {
    if ($text == "") {
        return "";
    }

    if ($salt == "") {
        $salt = 'DiAo74dOO09T48YESmuvbS0T';
    }

    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
}
```

//DECRYPTION

```
function decrypt($text, $salt = '') {
    if ($text == "") {
        return "";
    }

    if ($salt == "") {
        $salt = 'DiAo74dOO09T48YESmuvbS0T';
    }

    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
}
```

`AFdT9sa81krHkp/GoYCSwh7/lZn/gLZLHJSldi5/QCU=` this string I had encrypted using the above encryption function, but I want it to decrypt it using `OPENSSL`. I used the following code to decrypt it:

```
$string = 'AFdT9sa81krHkp/GoYCSwh7/lZn/gLZLHJSldi5/QCU=';   
$output = false;
$secret_key = 'DiAo74dOO09T48YESmuvbS0T';   
$secret_iv1 = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-ECB'));
$secret_iv = bin2hex($secret_iv1);
$key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);    
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

$output = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($string, 'aes-256-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA));
```

I want decrypted output as: `durhs-14767-w0163j1-89047`
Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Reformat your code please.
Also it is not clear to me, what are you acutally asking.

Comment: You can't use an IV with an ECB mode enabled cipher

Comment: This might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887285/exact-alternate-to-mcrypt-encrypt-in-php-7-2/54887672

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Saddly, you are on the wrong way.

Refer to :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#117667

> MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is not AES-256, it's a different variant of the
>   Rijndael block cipher.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

> AES is a variant of Rijndael which has a fixed block size of 128 bits,
>   and a key size of 128, 192, or 256 bits. By contrast, the Rijndael
>   specification per se is specified with block and key sizes that may be
>   any multiple of 32 bits, with a minimum of 128 and a maximum of 256
>   bits.

So you can not use OpenSSL's AES-256 to decrypt the MCrypt's output.

Some possible methods:

1. Keep using mcrypt by PECL's mcrypt extension (luckily, it is still there), until you can replace the legacy data totally.
2. Rewrite a correct RIJNDAEL-256 cipher in PHP.

Comment: Well this sucks balls. I understand why they deprecated mcrypt, but not providing a replacement for MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is a kick in the nuts if you already got data encrypted with that cipher. Glad that a PECL extension exists for now but there really should have been a native drop-in replacement.