# PHP error: Warning: openssl_decrypt(): Unknown cipher algorithm

Tags: php, encryption, configuration, openssl

When I run this:

```
<?php
openssl_decrypt('<string>', 'mcrypt_rijndael_256', '<key>', 0, '');
?>
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: openssl_decrypt(): Unknown cipher algorithm
```

I'm not sure if my VM is configured correctly to handle "mcrypt_rijndael_256". My phpinfo shows in the mcrypt section:

```
mcrypt
mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support   enabled
Version     2.5.8
Api No  20021217
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes
Supported modes     cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream
```

I have PHP 7.2.7. Do I need to add it to PHP somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `mcrypt's` algorithm name in `openssl` functions, which won't work, because *mcrypt* and *openssl* are different extensions. Also `RIJNDAEL_256` does not have a direct counterpart in *openssl*. See [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997338/mcrypt-rijndael-256-to-openssl-aes-256-ecb-conversion) for more details.