# Replace Mcrypt Encription with OpenSSL Encription for OpenCart CMS

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, opencart, mcrypt

I have `OpenCart 1.5.6.4` with `encryption.php` file in `system library folder`.
The codes in `encryption.php` are :

```
<?php
final class Encryption {
    private $key;
    private $iv;

    public function __construct($key) {
        $this->key = hash('sha256', $key, true);
        $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_RAND);
    }

    public function encrypt($value) {
        return strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->key, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv)), '+/=', '-_,');
    }

    public function decrypt($value) {
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->key, base64_decode(strtr($value, '-_,', '+/=')), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv));
    }
}
?>
```

For migration from `php 5.6` to `php 7.2` , I need to replace `Mcrypt Encription` with `OpenSSL Encription`.
I have replaced `mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_RAND)` with `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32, true)` , but for `encrypt function` and `decrypt function` , I do not know what `parameters` to use for these functions.
What changes needed in `encription.php` codes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MCrypt rijndael-256 to OpenSSL aes-256-ecb conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997338/mcrypt-rijndael-256-to-openssl-aes-256-ecb-conversion)

Comment: @jiri-hrazdil , If you read carefully you will find that these two questions are very different.

Comment: `openssl_encrypt($data=$value, $method="AES-256-CBC", $key=$this->key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv=$this->iv)`. I assume you want to use `"AES-256-CBC"` because your key is 256 bits, and you're using an IV. If you insist on using ECB (not recommended) just replace "CBC" with "ECB". Either way you won't be able to decrypt your data because AES doesn't support 256 block size.

Comment: @t.m.adam Its perfectly work.

Comment: Great! Since you're using PHP 7.2 and compatibility isn't an issue apparently, consider using an [AEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) cipher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally [wrote this](https://github.com/billynoah/opencart/blob/8afd4d8ee01a7e7f1555cfc6adbbcc37e073181b/upload/system/library/encryption.php) to address the empty iv warning that comes up with the [current encryption class for OC3](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/0ed2675b2bfb4321c2c2fb929fe90e1fac0555d2/upload/system/library/encryption.php):

> *Warning: openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended*

And recently backported it to work with OC1.5 for the precise reason you posted this question.  Here's a complete drop in replacement for `system/library/encryption.php` that will work on OC1.5.6.4 and PHP7.2:

```
final class Encryption {

    private $cipher = 'aes-256-ctr';
    private $digest = 'sha256';
    private $key;

    public function __construct($key) {
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    public function encrypt($value) {
        $key       = openssl_digest($this->key, $this->digest, true);
        $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->cipher);
        $iv        = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_length);
        return base64_encode($iv . openssl_encrypt($value, $this->cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
    }

    public function decrypt($value) {
        $result    = NULL;
        $key       = openssl_digest($this->key, $this->digest, true);
        $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->cipher);
        $value     = base64_decode($value);
        $iv        = substr($value, 0, $iv_length);
        $value     = substr($value, $iv_length);
        if (strlen($iv) == $iv_length) {
            $result = openssl_decrypt($value, $this->cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```